# Generate POJOs from JSON in Dependent Jar

Tags: java, json

Is there a tool that can generate POJOs from JSON schemas files that are contained in a jar?

We are creating a client to a service that generates an API jar (JSON schemas, RAML files, etc.) that can be downloaded as a Maven dependency.  Yes, we can unzip the jar file contents and run JSON to Java utils against them, but it would be nice if that could be automated as part of the build. Especially if the API is updated and then all we have to do is update the version in the pom.xml and regenerate the POJOs.

Answer (score 0):

1. While you're packaging the apis in the jar to be given to the client, you could include the domain objects (pojos) as well in the jar, rather than the schema. This would ensure that your versioned jar has both the service and the POJOs in sync and available as a single artifact.
2. Or, you could generate another jar with all the POJOs and hand it off along with the api jar.

I would prefer the first approach though to avoid version inconsistencies between the 2 sets (the apis and the pojos). You can use [proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net) to handpick and package the necessary pojos along with the api interfaces.

All these is assuming that you already have a pojo from which you would be generating the json data to be transferred over the network. If not, you could create this DTO POJOs and share them in the jar.